# Marking a disk as bootable in libvirt xml format

Tags: xml, libvirt

I was going through the doc regarding libvirt xml format [libvirt xml format](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsNICSBoot).

Could you please let me know how one specifies a disk as bootable. 
Is it the flag : boot order.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sections in the domain xml format that you need to look for the boot order:

Part 1: OS definition

```
<os>
    <type>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='rom'>/usr/lib/xen/boot/hvmloader</loader>
    <nvram template='/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd'>/var/lib/libvirt/nvram/guest_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <bootmenu enable='yes' timeout='3000'/>
    <smbios mode='sysinfo'/>
    <bios useserial='yes' rebootTimeout='0'/>
  </os>
```

This mainly defines, which type of disks will be used in the boot order.

Part 2: Disk Definition

```
<devices>
    <disk type='file' snapshot='external'>
      <driver name="tap" type="aio" cache="default"/>
      <source file='/var/lib/xen/images/fv0' startupPolicy='optional'>
        <seclabel relabel='no'/>
      </source>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <iotune>
        <total_bytes_sec>10000000</total_bytes_sec>
        <read_iops_sec>400000</read_iops_sec>
        <write_iops_sec>100000</write_iops_sec>
      </iotune>
      <boot order='2'/>
      <encryption type='...'>
        ...
      </encryption>
      <shareable/>
      <serial>
        ...
      </serial>
    </disk>
      ...
    <disk type='network'>
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw" io="threads" ioeventfd="on" event_idx="off"/>
      <source protocol="sheepdog" name="image_name">
        <host name="hostname" port="7000"/>
      </source>
      <target dev="hdb" bus="ide"/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <transient/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
</devices>
```

As you can see from the code above, you can also assign an order for each device. This way, if you have multiple hard disks assigned for the guest machine, libvirt will follow the given order in the devices definition.